# How to do scrollevent for bodymovin and control animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, after-effects, onscroll, bodymovin

I want to trigger animations on scroll for bodymovin [JSON] which can be controlled on scroll
i.e forward and reverse as well.

[Alfred](http://alfredservice.com) , Need similar kind of behavior .

Suggestions are welcome ,  How should I approach this OnScroll events ?

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can bind to the scroll event and then test to see where on the page it is scrolled to.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    //This will be how far down the page the user has scrolled
    var y = $(window).scrollTop();

    //do things here
})
```